# Magento 2 "PathInfoProcessor\Proxy” does not exist

Tags: magento2, database, elasticsearch, bin-magento

**My PHP version: 7.4.29**

I am run this command on **window 10**

```
php bin/magento setup:install --base-url="http://mat.magento.com/" --db-host="localhost" --db-name="magento2" --db-user="root" --db-password="root" --admin-firstname="admin" --admin-lastname="admin" --admin-email="user@example.com" --admin-user="admin" --admin-password="Admin@123456" --language="en_US" --currency="USD" --timezone="America/Chicago" --use-rewrites="1" --backend-frontname="admin" --search-engine=elasticsearch7 --elasticsearch-host="localhost" --elasticsearch-port=9200
```

**and facing error**

> Class “Magento\Backend\App\Request\PathInfoProcessor\Proxy” does not exist

Comment: Search this path in database  ,and delete entry from database

Comment: My database still empty >> https://prnt.sc/8BywJYYZ5OwV

Comment: you can follow this article step by step: https://magentip.com/install-magento-2-on-localhost-xampp-elasticsearch/

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
sudo chmod 777 -R .
sudo chown www-data: -R .
rm -rf var/cache/* var/page_cache/* var/generation/*
composer install
```

Comment: Not working On window sys

Answer (score 0):

I think this may help you :

https://www.thecoachsmb.com/solved-class-magentobackendapprequestpathinfoprocessorproxy-does-not-exist/

You can also check the permissions.

The data in the above command is correct.

Comment: i dont know what happend on window sys  >> https://prnt.sc/D6A5crMQUfQB

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this issue, you can try this.
1.Open the bootstrap.php file present in the app folder of magento directory.
2.Remove # from the beginning of the line
3.#ini_set(‘display_errors’, 1);
4.Save the file and refresh your browser to see the exact issue.

Comment: same error:: https://prnt.sc/D6A5crMQUfQB

Comment: which Magento version are you trying to install?

Comment: latest version 2.4

Comment: 2.4.3 or 2.4.4? because when you are trying to install latest magento which is 2.4.4 you must have php 8.1.

Comment: i have 2.4.4 and PHP Version 8.1.6 now let me know its working or not?

Comment: yeah its working with php 8.1

Comment: no dear its not working > https://prnt.sc/ATFDdOJ_kVLF

Answer (score 0):

In some cases this can be fixed be reinstalling composer modules by running command from the command line in project root:

```
rm -rf vendor && composer install
```